# Azure Functions - output bindings justification

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Can anyone tell me why I should use Azure Function output bindings (e.g. SendGrid or Twilio) rather than just using proper SDK (e.g. Sendgrid SDK) explicitly in my C# function to achieve my goal?

I suppose that using the output binding my code may be cleaner (no need to initialize Twilio client for example), but I still would rather use proper vendor SDK to get recent updates and features instantly.

Is there any other reason (performance?) to use output bindings?

Comment: simply put - its more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes down to control vs convenience:

Use the output binding when you want the quickest solution with the least amount of code. The output bindings have been designed with the Azure functions runtime in mind, i.e. how it scales as load increases and how that impacts the service you are targeting.

Use a custom connection in code backed by keyvault (for API keys) when you want more granular control over the interaction, where you can fine tune connection settings and how the interaction happens but keep in mind you need to code your interaction in a way that works in synergy with how the functions runtime behaves.

Comment: I'm not sure how output binding might have an impact on function scaling... At the end I'm only getting some pre-initialized object which I can use to _define_ my output, but this output then is handled by the function SDK. So overall amount of work to be done is the same IMHO. 
Is there some $ saving involved if I use output binding? I.e. my function executes faster because I don't need to send my output myself, but SDK does it after my function finishes. Not sure basically how Azure charges for the function execution time in details.

Comment: The actual binding will take milliseconds, then your output to the binding may take some time which you will be billed for. In terms scaling, if you have 10,000 concurrent instances of a function when at high load, they may overload the target (e.g. CosmosDB). This needs to be handled. Coming back to CosmosDB, I don't believe you cannot apply ConnectionPolicy in output bindings, so if you want to control this (e.g. preferred regions), you need to roll your own

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is [cleaner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8p8RmOg9iw&feature=youtu.be).
2. Your style is more declarative and easier to understand.
3. You don't worry about managing connections.
4. You can share data from your trigger to our bindings.